# How to split string by multiple bracket types but still keep the brackets in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, data-structures, split

Is there a way to split a string into small part and store into vector.

For example:

A string: `str = "(a b c) d e f [[g h i]]"`. The output expected is:

```
(a b c)
d e f
[[g h i]]
```

Sample code:

```
vector<string> token;
string str = "(a b c)d e f[[g h i]]";
string bracketS = "()[]";
istringstream ss(str);
string section;
string tok;

while (getline(ss,section)) {
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = section.find_first_of(bracketS);
    while (end != string::npos) {
        tok = section.substr(start, end - start);
        token.push_back(tok);
        start = end + 1;
        end = section.find_first_of(bracketS, start);
    }
}
```

And output is without the brackets:

```
      a b c
      d e f
      g h i
```

Tried to adjust my `section.substr(start-1, end - start+2)`
Then my output is:

```
(a b c)
) d e f [
[g h i]
```

Why the middle vector is wrong.

Also tried do strtok. But the output is the same as the first one.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What about simply using [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)?

Comment: If you knew nothing about regex, but had a little savvy in elementary data structures, you could try a `std::stack` and knowing when to`push` and `pop` could be used, and then there is no need for strtok.  Your attempt using "brute force" parsing is a naive approach.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sakefully, the OP doesn't use `strtok()` in their code at all, or did I miss something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP mentioned `strtok` in his post.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with nested brackets. For example, what would be the result of `(a b c) (d [e f] g)`?

Comment: @JimMischel exactly! My project is tokenize a string. For example, as my string up there, my project will figure out the string inside the round Bracket will be a COMMAND, the string inside of double square bracket will be LINK, and the other will be TEXT. So, when I print out its will be:
Command: (a b c)
Text: d e f
Link: [[g h i]]

Comment: So the strings are always of the form `(COMMAND) TEXT [[LINK]]`? Can the brackets exist anywhere other than as delimiters? That is, would `this [ is a bracket` be a valid `TEXT` string?

Comment: @JimMischel It will be any form. But the concept will be the same. The COMMAND alway begin with the '( and close with')', same as LINK, anything outside of brackets is TEXT. But it will only take the first bracket. For example, if found '(' after, a '[', will skip that pair of (), go find the next ']'.

Comment: I suggest that you write down a formal definition of your rules before you try writing code that will parse your strings. What you've supplied so far, and your coding attempt, show that you don't fully understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution with a stack for parsing and throwing a parsing_error if there are opening brackets missing closing brackets or the closing bracket mismatches the opening one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const auto Brackets = { std::make_pair('(', ')'), std::make_pair('[', ']') };

const auto is_opening_bracket = [](const char c) {
    return std::find_if(Brackets.begin(), Brackets.end(),
            [c](const auto& p) { return p.first == c; } ) != Brackets.end();
};
const auto is_closing_bracket = [](const char c) {
    return std::find_if(Brackets.begin(), Brackets.end(),
            [c](const auto& p) { return p.second == c; } ) != Brackets.end();
};

const auto get_opening_bracket = [](const char c) {
    const auto p = std::find_if(Brackets.begin(), Brackets.end(), [c](const auto& p) { return p.second == c; });
    if (p == Brackets.end())
        return '0';

    return p->first;
};

struct parsing_error {};

int main() {
    const std::string str = "(a b c)d e f[[g h i]]";

    std::stack<char> brackets;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;

    for (const auto c : str) {
        if (is_opening_bracket(c)) {
            if (!token.empty() && brackets.empty()) {
                tokens.push_back(token);
                token.clear();
            }

            brackets.push(c);
            token += c;
        } else if (is_closing_bracket(c)) {
            if (brackets.top() != get_opening_bracket(c))
                throw parsing_error();

            brackets.pop();
            token += c;

            if (brackets.empty()) {
                tokens.push_back(token);
                token.clear();
            }
        } else {
            token += c;
        }

    }

    if (!brackets.empty())
        throw parsing_error();

    for (const auto& token : tokens)
        std::cout << token << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good effort, however when answers get posted, a little background on how the solution works (a rundown on the algorithm, links to further reading, etc.) is better than just posting the code.